# background image not working in IE when set through JS

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set the background image from javascript end. My code is working fine in Chrome but when tested in IE11, the image is not shown.

```
function setApplicationLogo() {
    var name = getApplicationName();
    if (name) {
        document.getElementById('loginLogo').style.background = 'url(./images/custom/' + logo[name] + ')no-repeat center bottom';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('loginLogo').style.background = 'url(./images/logo77.gif)no-repeat center bottom';
    }
}
```

I know the fix is fairly straight forward but I am scratching my head for the past 2-3 hours. I have tried changing `background` to `backgroundImage` and removing adding/removing space before `no-repeat`but nothing worked for IE. So please dont mark this as duplicate.

Comment: What can you read back in your developer toolbar (F12)? Is there an override in your CSS-file? Also put a space in between for readability.

Comment: I don't have IE at hand but I did find another answer mentioning no space before no-repeat is a problem in IE. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14530087/2652134

Also is `logo[name]` escaped ?

Comment: There is no override in IE. can you please let me know where do I need to put space for readability?

Comment: @Cling change `)no-repeat` to `) no-repeat`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think proplem is that you have wrong syntax. Basically *.background* has this syntax:

```
object.style.background = "color image repeat attachment position size origin clip|initial|inherit"
```

where *image* is

```
object.style.backgroundImage = "url('URL')|none|initial|inherit"
```

So, I think proplem is in quotes. Path to image should be as a string value for *url*. 
Example:

```
document.getElementById("myDIV").style.background = "url('smiley.gif') blue repeat-x center";
```

So, try this:

```
document.getElementById('loginLogo').style.background = "url('./images/custom/'" + logo[name] + "') no-repeat center bottom";
```